# The Existence of $n-1$ Dimensional Linear Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $K$ be an infinite field, $V$ is an $n$ dimensional($n>1$) vector space over $K$.

$\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_s \in V$ are non-zero vectors.

Proof there exists an $n-1$ dimensional subspace $H\subset V$, that $$a_i\not\in H,\forall 1\leq i\leq s.$$
I tried using the fact that a vector space over an infinite field cannot be a finite union of proper subspaces, but have no idea.

Comment: Hint: every independent set in a vector space is contained within some basis.

Comment: For example, if we have ten million points in the Euclidean plane, still there is some line that misses them all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a linear map

$$ \phi: V \rightarrow K, \ \phi(\alpha_i)=1. $$

Then the kernel of this map has the properties you're looking for.

Edit: The above solution works only in the case where the vectors are assumed to be independet. If this is not the case, one need to work a bit more.

Let $(\beta_j)_{j=1}^n$ be a basis of V. Again, we want to define a linear map

$$ \phi: V \rightarrow K , \ \phi(\beta_j)=b_j$$

such that the kernel has the desired properties. We need to find $(b_j)_{j=1}^n$ such that $\phi(\alpha_j)\neq 0$. Write

$$ \alpha_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}\beta_j $$

and set $A=(a_{i,j})_{\substack{1\leq i\leq s\\ 1\leq j \leq n}} \in K^{s\times n}$. W.l.o.g. we may assume that $A$ is in row echelon normal form, otherwise we transform our basis $(\beta_j)_{j=1}^n$ accordingly. I will now show how to choose the $b_j$ at an example.

We take

$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &0 \\ a_{2,1} &1 &0 \\ a_{3,1}& a_{3,2} & 0 \\ a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & 1 \\ a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

We need to find $(b_i)_{i=1}^3$ such that

$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &0 \\ a_{2,1} &1 &0 \\ a_{3,1}& a_{3,2} & 0 \\ a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & 1 \\ a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & 0\end{pmatrix} \circ \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

is different from zero in every coordinate. We choose $b_1=1$. From the second line we get

$$ b_2\neq -a_{2,1}.$$

From the third line we get either no further condition (if $a_{3,2}=0$) or otherwise

$$ b_2 \neq -\frac{a_{3,1}}{a_{3,2}}.$$

From the fifth line we get again either nothing or

$$ b_2 \neq - \frac{a_{5,1}}{a_{5,2}}.$$

As $K$ is infinite $K\setminus \{0 -a_{2,1}, -\frac{a_{3,1}}{a_{3,2}}, - \frac{a_{5,1}}{a_{5,2}} \} \neq \emptyset$. Choose some $b_2$. The forth line finally gives us a condition for $b_3$. Namely,

$$ b_3 \neq -a_{4,1}- a_{4,2} b_2. $$

Again by infiniteness of $K$ we may choose such a $b_3\neq 0$.

In the general case, we set again $b_1=1$. Then we determine all the conditions, that only involve $b_1, b_2$. These are finitely many conditions, hence, we may choose such a $b_2$. Then we play the same game with $b_3$ and so on. Note that no row can be identically zero, as our original vectors are assumed to be nonzero.

Comment: How to define $\phi$ if the $\alpha_i$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: @GEdgar I think this idea is the right approach, it's obviously true if vectors are independent, if they are dependent, we can find a independent set and give proper value for them so that every $\phi(\alpha_i)\not=0$

Comment: I am truly sorry, I did not read carefull enough, I assumed them to be independent. I'll edit my answer.